# Node + telnet + OS X

Tags: javascript, node.js

Good day.

```
var events = require('events');
var net = require('net');

var channel = new events.EventEmitter();
channel.clients = {};
channel.subscriptions = {};

channel.on('join', function(id, client) {
this.clients[id] = client;
this.subscriptions[id] = function(senderId, message) {
    if (id != senderId) {
        this.clients[id].write(message);
    }
}
this.on('broadcast', this.subscriptions[id]);
});

var server = net.createServer(function(client) {
var id = client.remoteAddress + ':' + client.remotePort;

client.on('connect', function() {
    channel.emit('join', id, client);
});
client.on('data', function(data) {
    data = data.toString();
    channel.emit('broadcast', id, data);
});
});
server.listen(8888);
```

When i run server and connect via telnet 'broadcast' emit not working. Example from "Node.js in Action". Code from book's archive not working too. Help please. What's maybe wrong? I was try id's generator change to just strong inc "i" and omit ...if (id != senderId)... but not working!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the callback function to `net.createServer` is called, it already implies that a client connected. Also, I think the `connect` event isn't even generated by `net.createServer` anyway.

So instead of waiting for a `connect` event before you emit 'join', just emit it right away:

```
var server = net.createServer(function(client) {
  var id = client.remoteAddress + ':' + client.remotePort;

  // we got a new client connection:
  channel.emit('join', id, client);

  // wait for incoming data and broadcast it:
  client.on('data', function(data) {
    data = data.toString();
    channel.emit('broadcast', id, data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Reading the same book, encountered the same issue - this fixed it!

Comment: Reading the same book, asked the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784894/node-js-tcp-server-connect-event-is-not-emitted

Comment: Had exactly the same problem. This fixed it! Thank you @robertklep